# Query: CSS Overwriting reg

Tags: html, css

consider following mark-up:

```
<div>
  Hey Senorita
</div>

<div class="alkaline">
  Hey Alkaline
</div>

<div>
  Hey Amour!
</div>
```

coupled with following CSS:

```
* {
  color:pink;
}
div.alkaline {
  color:grey;
}
div {
  color:orange;
}
```

after saving the file I would expect text inside all of the `<div>` to be `orange` but it turns out like this:-

[image]

Someone please explain why isn't the css overwriting not happening in this case?

Comment: this is because you defined in the stylesheet that all divs must have color - orange but the the div containing class alkaline has color grey

Comment: if you want the text to be orange then you need to remove this div.alkaline { color:grey; } or the second option is you can give div with color orange an !important like this div { color: orange !important }

Comment: May I ask you that why you added class alkaline to one div only if you want to keep everything common. please explain a little bit more about the scenario.

Comment: @shivam I had this doubt for a long ago. I thought, in this case, css must overwrite ```color``` property of all ```div``` and set it to ```orange```. I was taught that css runs "top-to-bottom" style and properties are prone to be overwritten.

Comment: * {
  color:pink;
}
div {
  color:grey;
}
div {
  color:orange;
}

Comment: this is the case you are asking for

Comment: same element with 2 different properties, it will prioritize the last one in your case color - orange

Comment: i hope your doubt is resolved

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is prioritizing .alkaline class instead of div for that. If you want everything can you change the color from grey to orange or you can remove that . alkaline styling part from your css part.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the middle div is gray is because of CSS specificity rules. The div.alkaline is more specific than just the div.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

for more info on how the weight is calculated.